# How to add bordered data labels to R plotly bar chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using R and have added data labels to a bar chart using plotly's add_text() function. However, I am wondering how I could add data labels to a filled & bordered rectangle to make them easier to see. I wasn't sure if I could do this using add_annotations(). I was hoping to render something like the data labels on this chart:

[image]

Here is an example of my current code:

```
my_tibble <- tibble(mins = runif(10,10,30),
                    week = 1:10,
                    exercise = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a"),
                    weight = runif(10,150,160))

plot_ly(data = my_tibble, hoverinfo = "none") %>%
  
  add_trace(
    type = 'bar',
    x = ~week,
    y = ~mins,
    color = ~exercise,
    hovertext = ~weight,
    hovertemplate = paste('<b>Week</b>: %{x}', "%{hovertext}", '<extra></extra>')
  ) %>%
  
  add_trace(
    type = 'bar',
    x = ~week,
    y = ~mins
  ) %>%
  
  layout(
    barmode = 'stack'
  )%>%
  
  add_text(
    x = ~week,
    y = 8,
    text = "label",
    showlegend = F
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is to add the text as annotations, instead of a trace.

I added this to the code you have without changing anything you wrote:

```
  layout(annotations = list(x = ~week, y = 8, showarrow = F, 
                           bgcolor = "white", text = "label"))
```

[image]